# Read NFC hardware information of NFC enabled smartphone

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to read details of NFC hardware in an android device?

Edit : More specifically, any info that can be used to uniquely identify the NFC chip.

Comment: Specifically what details are you looking for?